# Как убрать все слова со знаком " - " из csv

Tags: python

Есть test.csv, в ней есть условно названия:
`велосипед -штаны -+кеды лента`

Мне надо удалить все слова, которые начинаются со знака минус и чтобы на выходе получилось:
`велосипед лента`

И сохранить в test_ext.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, алгоритм такой

```
import re
of = open("text_ext.csv", "w+")

with open("text.csv", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = re.sub(r"\-\S*\s?", "", line)
        of.write(line)

of.close()
```

Comment: спасибо. Сработало, только сделала немного по своему, но суть та же.

Answer (score 0):

Надо читать файл по строкам. Далее регулярное выражение для удаления слов.

```
import re

text = "Есть test.csv, в ней есть условно названия: велосипед -штаны -+кеды лента"
result = re.sub(r"([\-][+\w]*)", "", text)
print(result)
```

Результат

```
Есть test.csv, в ней есть условно названия: велосипед   лента
```